# OkHttp API rate limit

Tags: okhttp, rate, rate-limiting

Has OkHttp an integrated way of complying with an api rate request limit, or it has to be implemented externally? either case a hint on where to start is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

An [interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) combined with a [RateLimiter](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-rate-limiter) from Guava was a good solution to avoid receiving a 429 HTTP code.

Let's suppose we want a limit of 3 calls per second:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class RateLimitInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    private RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(3);

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        rateLimiter.acquire(1);
        return chain.proceed(chain.request());
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware that RateLimiter is marked as unstable (@Beta). https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.java#L95

Answer (score 8):

As @jesse-wilson said, you can do this with [OkHttp Interceptors](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors)

Here's an example. First define a custom Interceptor. The api I call responds with HTTP Code 429 when the rate limit is hit. You will need to check for the particular HTTP Code or Header in your own api that indicates a rate error, and sleep for an appropriate time.

```
public class RateLimitInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    public RateLimitInterceptor() {
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

        // 429 is how the api indicates a rate limit error
        if (!response.isSuccessful() && response.code() == 429) {
            System.err.println("Cloudant: "+response.message());

            // wait & retry
            try {
                System.out.println("wait and retry...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Next add the Interceptor to where you build the OkHttp request. Here's an example of my builder...

```
public static Response fetchPaged(HttpUrl url) throws IOException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new BasicAuthInterceptor(username, password))
                .addInterceptor(new RateLimitInterceptor())
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        return client
                .newCall(request)
                .execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build an [interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) to track requests made, and potentially throttle or fail requests if the rate is too high.

Comment: It's the throttling part I'dont know how to implement, the ideal would be to tell the client to delay the queue, as the requests can came simultaneously from several fragments, but I can't find a way to do that

Comment: There's a rate limiter in Guava. You might either use it, or study its source code to get started. Also consider using OkHttp’s async API to limit how many threads are active. Dispatcher has options to configure that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip I'll look into it

Answer (score 1):

I also have the problem.
I want limit rate when upload large file by post. I read OkHttp Interceptors code. And find can limite body write to limit upload rate.

```
public class RateLimitingRequestBody extends RequestBody {

private MediaType mContentType;
private File mFile;
private int mMaxRate;    // ms/bit

private RateLimitingRequestBody(@Nullable final MediaType contentType, final File file, int rate){
    mContentType = contentType;
    mFile = file;
    mMaxRate = rate;
}

@Override
public MediaType contentType() {
    return mContentType;
}

@Override
public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {

    Source source = null;

    try {
        source = Okio.source(mFile);
        writeAll(sink, source);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        Util.closeQuietly(source);
    }
}


public long writeAll(BufferedSink sink, Source source) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if (source == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("source == null");
    } else {
        long totalBytesRead = 0L;

        long readCount;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while((readCount = source.read(sink.buffer(), 8192L)) != -1L) {
            totalBytesRead += readCount;
            sink.emitCompleteSegments();

            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(time == start) continue;
            long rate = (totalBytesRead * 8) / (time - start);
            NLog.v("writeAll","totalBytesRead:"+totalBytesRead+"B "+ " Rate:"+rate*1000+"bits");

            if(rate > mMaxRate/1000){
                int sleep = (int) (totalBytesRead * 8 * 1000 / mMaxRate - (time - start));
                NLog.d("writeAll", "sleep:"+sleep);
                Thread.sleep(sleep+50);
            }
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long rate = (totalBytesRead * 8 * 1000) / ((end - start));
        NLog.e("writeAll","totalBytesRead:"+totalBytesRead+"B "+ " Rate:"+rate+"bits"+" total time:"+(end-start));
        return totalBytesRead;
    }
}


public static RequestBody createRequestBody(@Nullable final MediaType contentType, final File file, int rate) {
    if (file == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("content == null");
    } else {
        return new RateLimitingRequestBody(contentType, file, rate);
    }
}
```

}

May be this can help you.